# Notation for intrinsic charge carrier

Tags: terminology, semiconductor-physics, notation

What exactly is $n_{\textrm{i}}$? It is said to be the intrinsic charge carrier, but for pure semiconductors, $n_{\textrm{h}} = n_{\textrm{e}} = n_{\textrm{i}}$, is $n_{\textrm{i}}$ not the sum of both $n_{\textrm{e}}$ and $n_{\textrm{h}}$ and refers to the total no. intrinsic charge carriers per unit volume?

Answer (score 0):

This is a carrier concentration for a pure semiconductor in equilibrium. If it is doped it can give an equation for calculating carrier density. For example, il the semiconductor is slightly doped and the Fermi level is situated more then kT to conduction and valence bands $(E_C - E_F) >> kT$, $(E_F - E_V) >> kT$, than $n_e \cdot n_h = n_i^2$

Answer (score 0):

No, the intrinsic charge carrier concentration is the concentration of the electron or the hole concentration, not their sum. As you pointed out yourself, in an intrinsic semiconductor in equilibrium electron and hole concentrations are always equal.